# Disable Trigger for a particular DELETE Query

Tags: sql, ruby, psql

I have a ruby app. The app is doing the insert,update and delete on a particular table.

It does 2 kinds of INSERT, one insert should insert a record in the table and also into trigger_logs table. Another insert is just to insert the record into the table and do nothing. Another way to put it is, one kind of insert should log that the 'insert' happened into another table and another kind of insert should just be a normal insert. Similarly, there are 2 kinds of UPDATE and DELETE also.

I have achieved the 2 types of INSERT and UPDATE using a trigger_disable. Please refer to the trigger code below.

So, when I do a INSERT, I will set the trigger_disable boolean to true if I don't want to log the trigger. Similarly I am doing for an UPDATE too.

But I am not able to differentiate between the 2 kinds of DELETE as I do for an INSERT or UPDATE. The DELETE action is logged for both kinds of DELETE.

**NOTE:** I am logging all the changes that are made under a certain condition, which will be determined by the ruby app. If the condition is not satisfied, I just need to do a normal INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE accordingly.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_#{@table_name}()
      RETURNS TRIGGER
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
      AS $$
        DECLARE
          changed_row_id varchar(100);
        BEGIN

          IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
          -- When the trigger is due to a delete

            IF (OLD.trigger_disable IS NULL) 
               OR (OLD.trigger_disable = false) THEN
            -- Prevent the trigger if trigger_disable is 'true'
            -- The Problem is here: This insertion into the 
            -- trigger_logs table happens
            -- for all the delete statements. 
            -- But during certain deletes I should not
            -- insert into trigger_logs

              INSERT INTO trigger_logs (table_name, action, row_id, dirty) 
              VALUES (
                '#{@table_name}', 
                CAST(TG_OP AS Text), 
                OLD.id,
                true
              ) RETURNING id into changed_row_id;

            END IF;

            RETURN OLD;

          ELSE
          -- The trigger is due to a Insert or Update

            IF (NEW.trigger_disable IS NULL) 
               OR (NEW.trigger_disable = false) THEN
            -- Prevent the trigger if trigger_disable is 'true'

              INSERT INTO trigger_logs (table_name, action, row_id, dirty) 
              VALUES (
                '#{@table_name}',
                CAST(TG_OP AS Text),
                NEW.id,
                true
              ) RETURNING id into changed_row_id;

            ELSE
              NEW.trigger_disable := false;

            END IF;

            RETURN NEW;
          END IF;

        END
```

Comment: Well, what are your criteria for when to fire the trigger or not? What makes that decision and how? The question is pretty unclear, I'm really not sure what you're getting at. You've said (per deleted answer) that [the `WHEN` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) isn't what you want, but it's not clear what your decision making process for when to fire the trigger or not actually is.

Comment: The decision is made by a ruby app, which uses https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg

Comment: ... but that app isn't necessarily what's doing the update/delete. So how's it supposed to control a trigger invocation? Do you want to call into the app from within the trigger to ask it what to do? If not, how do you intend to convey the information on when to act or not act? I suspect that if you properly specify this question in terms of describing the required behaviour you'll be halfway to solving your own problem.

Comment: I have updated the question, with additional details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here and guess that you're trying to contextually control whether triggers get fired.

If so, perhaps you can use a session variable?

```
BEGIN;

SET LOCAL myapp.fire_trigger = 'false';

DELETE FROM ...;

COMMIT;
```

and in your trigger, test it:

```
IF current_setting('myapp.fire_trigger') = 'true' THEN
```

Note, however, that if the setting is missing from a session you won't get NULL, you'll get an error:

```
regress=> SELECT current_setting('myapp.xx');
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "myapp.xx"
```

so you'll want to:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET myapp.fire_trigger = 'true';
```

Also note that the parameter is `text` not boolean.

Finally, there's no security on session variables. So it's not useful for security audit, since anybody can come along and just `SET myapp.fire_trigger = 'false'`.

(If this doesn't meet your needs, you might want to re-think whether you should be doing this with triggers at all, rather than at the application level).

Comment: Thanks for being patient. I want to say why your answer would not work. In my app, I set the session variable and I execute the DELETE statement. What if in between the execution of these 2 statements, a DELETE for which I need to log gets executed?. So as you see the way I am controlling the 2 kinds of INSERT and UPDATE(if you don't understand this, please inbox me. I would be happy to explain). Which I think is the best way to do. I want a similar way for DELETE too.

Comment: @Charizard_ Your app controls the session var, so your app must make sure to execute the non-logged delete, then commit to clear the session var. Or reset it. It's session-local, so it can't affect other sessions - maybe you're thinking it's global? Anyway, if you cannot do that, then it sounds like your app design is busted. You need to rethink how you're doing all this - either find a way to put the logging decision in PL/PgSQL, or move the logging into the app.  I cannot help you if you can't explain the app's logic.